# Prolog evaluating how two lists compare to eachother

Tags: list, prolog

Note: Near complete beginner to logic programming

I need to compare two lists of integers and figure out if one is greater, greater-equal, or they are  both equal.

For example:

```
compare_list([1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 4], C).
C = greater,
C = greater-equal.
compare_list([1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 4], C).
C = equal.
```

So far the closest I have been able to get has been...

```
compare_list([],[],_).
compare_list([X|XS],[Y|YS],C):-
  X > Y,
  compare_list(XS,YS,C),
  C = 'greater'.

compare_list([X|XS],[Y|YS],C):-
  X >= Y,
  compare_list(XS,YS,C),
  C = 'greater-equal'.

compare_list([X|XS],[Y|YS],C):-
  X == Y,
  compare_list(XS,YS,C),
  C = 'equal'.
```

Now that obviously doesn't work as needed because it is always comparing the first element of each list and seeing if the C value holds for all of the values.  However I cannot think of a way to make it work as intended.

Edit:
The earlier a value is in a list, the more important it is.  So [2,2] > [1,3] > [1,2]

Tips would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Edit:
Solved by waiting until the end to assign C to anything.

Comment: When, according to you, a list is greater than another?

Comment: Each value of the list is more important the more to the left it is. So [2, 0, 0] is greater than [1, 2, 3] which is greater than [1, 2, 2].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your definition of "greater" there is no need to continue the recursion after you find that X>Y. If you reach the end of the recursion (as chac said) you'll know that the two lists are equal.

To get "greater-equal" you should instead check that X is not less than Y. You may think of this as "if X is less than Y than fail". Take a look at [negation as failure](http://www.google.it/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=negation%20as%20failure&source=web&cd=1&sqi=2&ved=0CDsQFjAA&url=http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negation_as_failure&ei=Tn5zT96qBamj4gSj1t3wDg&usg=AFQjCNFgl6n7-rKDRF_kMpMOsSJNd5wGcg&sig2=EutIwRC34LtX5J8LwEi_TQ).

Answer (score 3):

In your solution you use `(>)/2`, `(>=)/2` and `(==)/2`.  The first two will evaluate their arguments as arithmetic expressions prior to a comparison. And `(==)/2` will compare due to term order. You will have to decide for one of them or another term order. But you cannot mix them.

The second remark is that you would also need something as 'less' as a result.

If two elements already compare as `(<)/2`, there is no need for further comparison.

Also, equality can only be stated in the fact, but not before.

---

Consider to use the built-in predicate `compare/3`:

```
?- compare(R, [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 4]).
   R = (<).
?- compare(R, [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]).
   R = (=).
```

Should you write your own comparison predicate, better use the very same argument order and the same terms as result. That is, `<`, `=`, and `>`. It does not make a lot of sense, to expect `>=` to be a result. After all, two identical lists would then have three different solutions `=<`, `=`, `>=`.

From your description, it is not clear to me what you expect, if both lists are of different length.

Answer (score 1):

You can stop comparing at the first ineguagliance. If you reach the end of (both) lists, that means lists are equals.

Answer (score 0):

The following code will check whether two list are equal or not

```
is_equal([],[]).
is_equal([H1|T1],[H2|T2]):- H1=:=H2,is_equal(T1,T2).
```